# Any way to get EE to upload not-properly encoded mp3s?

Tags: file-uploads

**here's the problem (edit):**

I'm unable to upload some mp3s through the publish page or the file manager, whereas other mp3s would upload just fine. Now, thanks to the assistance of a support person at the host (Nexcess), I've found that the mp3's that don't work didn't have all the encoding they need, and the mp3's that *did* work had the encoding, like this:

The mp3's that were working look like this:

```
$ file /dev/audio-upload/*.mp3
example01.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.2.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 192 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
example02.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.2.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 192 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
example03.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.2.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 160 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
```

The mp3's that weren't working look like this (they're missing the encoding info):

```
$ file /dev/mp3s-for-eval/*.mp3
example01.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.2.0, contains:
example02.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.2.0, contains:
example03.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.2.0, contains:
```

So a solution was to re-convert the unencoded files to mp3. But the problem remains: the mp3's that wouldn't upload (the ones missing the encoding info) play just fine. Is there a way to get EE to allow these un-encoded mp3's so my client doesn't get confused if they have files like this?

Also, these test mp3's that didn't upload were created by converting AIFF files in iTunes; any ideas as to why they didn't get the encoding?

**(this is my original question:)**

I'm having a mysterious time trying to get certain mp3's uploaded through a Grid field.

I'm developing a music site using EE 2.10.1; one of the channels is "Albums" which holds info on different music CDs. In this channel I have a Grid field that contains info about the different tracks on the CD and also the mp3 of the track.

My upload location is set to "all file types" and when I check the PHP info, it looks like the max file size allowed is 64MB.

When I try to upload the mp3's I need for the first entry, I get a cryptic "file not allowed" message; 'cryptic' because it's not saying it's an invalid file type or that the file is too big:

[image: file not allowed screenshot]

So I’ve been testing to see what I can--and can’t--upload. I've been able to successfully upload a 13.7MB jpg through the Grid field, so I'm assuming that size isn't an issue (the mp3's are all smaller than that).

Further testing reveals that I'm able to upload *some* mp3's, ranging in size from 1.4MB to 8.2MB. But the majority of mp3's I try give me the error message. Also, I've tried uploading the mp3's that don't work directly through the File Manager, but I also get the error message that way.

Any ideas or thoughts about what the problem could be? I have no idea if this is somehow a server issue, an EE issue or an issue with particular files (I can play the mp3's that won’t upload, so I don’t think they’re corrupt).

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on this, the issue turned out to be incorrectly created MP3s! I was using iTunes to convert AIFFs into MP3s and for some reason -- even though the MP3s would play -- they were not correctly formatted in some way. Converting the AIFFs with a different program correctly formatted the MP3s and then they would upload. So the problem was that EE was seeing bad file formats, there wasn't any size-limit or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable XSS filtering in your security preferences. It looks like EE flags those files as suspicious.

Comment: Thanks for this thought, although it doesn't seem to have any effect on the issue. You can see my edit above that explains more about what is happening.